# How to change flutter gradient png/svg color with blendmode.color but keep background transparent

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

I'm working on a Flutter project where I'm using the SvgPicture.asset widget to display an SVG image. I want to change the color of the SVG image from a red gradient to a blue gradient, but I'm encountering an issue with the background color.

I've tried using BlendMode.srcIn, which allows me to change the color with a transparent background, but it results in a solid color, not a gradient. Ideally, I would like to use BlendMode.color, but when I do, it introduces an unwanted background color.

````
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class TestScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/business_card/Frame.svg',
          colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(Colors.blue, BlendMode.color),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```

[![What i'm try to achieve][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ht4Q.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension code to add gradient to widget :

```
 extension Extension on Widget {
     gradient({required Gradient gradient }) => ShaderMask(
        blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn,
        shaderCallback: (bouenter code herends) => gradient.createShader(
          Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height),
        ),
        child: this,
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I tried this and this is not what i want. Did you check this image "https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ht4Q.jpg". If not please check so you will understand what i want.Thank you for your replay